# htaccess 301 redirect replacing only two letters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to write a .htaccess 301 redirect to do the following.  I want

http://www.mydomain.com/idx/RX-9968176 to point to 
http://www.mydomain.com/idx/AB-9968176.

The only thing that will change is instead of "RX" I want "AB" inserted.  This will be for hundreds of pages so I can not do each one individually.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/idx/RX-(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/idx/AB-$1
```

Although you can use a relative path for the URL-path, there is a possibility it might cause a redirect loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/idx/RX-(.*)$ /idx/AB-$1 [L]
```